# Distributed Tracing -JaegerUi not showing service name

Tags: .net-6.0, open-telemetry, zipkin, jaeger, distributed-tracing

I'm trying to implement distributed tracing in .net 6. I am running jaeger from cmd by using `.\jaeger-all-in-one.exe`. I am able to run and i can view through `http://localhost:16686/`. now I added below code in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetryTracing(builder =>
        {
            builder
                .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService(" Api"))
                 .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                 .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
                 
                .AddEntityFrameworkCoreInstrumentation(options => options.SetDbStatementForText = true)
                .AddSource(namer) // when we manually create activities, we need to setup the sources here
                .AddZipkinExporter(options =>
                {
                    // not needed, it's the default
                    options.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans");
                })
                .AddJaegerExporter(options =>
                {
                    options.AgentHost = "localhost";
                    options.AgentPort = 6831; 
                });

        });
```

After adding this when I run my web api project I am not able see my service name in jaeger ui.

how to fix this?

i have tried all suggestions, yt videos and chatgpt suggestions. but still not able to view my service name in jaeger ui list.

i need to list my service name so that i can trace all my apis request

Comment: Don't forget that the AddJaegerExporter is about to be deprecated https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Jaeger/README.md